# Determining the ideal parameters for KeyGraph Algorithm

Tags: data-mining, text-mining, graphs

Is there a method to determine the ideal amount of Keywords, High Frequency Terms and High Key Terms for the Keygraph?

To determine the ideal amount of topics for the LDA you have Topic Coherence or Perplexity for example. Is there something similiar for KeyGraph?

Does someone here have experience with the KeyGraph and can help?